# Unable to read image data

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to cook my own RSS reader and want to show thumbnail images. Following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6_F6Kpjd-Q) tutorial as an example. Changed the model source to `http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=uk`. Thumbnails are showing on Windows 7 OS but not on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64Bit. I'm getting all these errors

`QML Image: Error decoding: http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/1C4F/production/_84574270_84571400.jpg: Unable to read image data`

This image does exist as I can see that working on Windows and also using the browser.

Can someone please help what I need to do? Installed `libjpeg62` as per some suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can reproduce this too, on a fresh, 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: http://wiki.qt.io/Building-Qt-5-from-Git mentions nothing about it, either.

Comment: Make sure you've added the "widgets" Qt module in your pro file, I *think* that's required for JPEG support.

Comment: How are you testing your application? You must properly deploy it prior to running it, so that all the required plugins, including image plugins, will be accessible to it. Or you can be compiling against the system Qt, but it's not clear what you do here.

Comment: @MrEricSir these are all the modules. `QT += qml quick widgets webkit webkitwidgets`

Comment: @KubaOber I'm using Qt Creator which has proper toolkit / build tools configured. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: So, you're running it from within Qt Creator? Great. That should be working, then. What does `qDebug() << QImageReader::supportedImageFormats()` say?